# How to escape angle brackets in BIML ScriptTask .cs file

Tags: biml

I have a ScriptTask that looks like:

```
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
  private Dictionary<int,string> map;
... more code ...
}
```

BIML chokes on these angle brackets for the Dictionary though.  I know that I can change all of the brackets to `&lt;` and `&gt;` but I'm wondering if anyone knows a way other than find/replace to escape these for the whole file?

Answer (score 2):

Derp.  Enclose the code in a `<![CDATA[code...]]>` block... In this case, my whole file is the code.

Alternatively hackish -> `using MyType = Dictionary&lt;int,string&gt;;`